# I have two large tables and I need to see the change in numbers across multiple rows

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

EDIT:  I need to add some context.  Below is a small sample table.  I am using 200 columns across 30,000 rows.

I am in Excel and Access.  I am fairly good at Excel but not so good with Access.

I have two very large, Excel crashing, tables with matching criteria across multiple rows.  I would like to return the change in amounts between the two table for each column by matching three criteria.  See picture below.

Between the two tables the rows do not flow in the same direction and one table has a lot of extra rows with no corresponding values in the other.

[image: table example]

What is my best option?

Comment: What  result do you want?  The table difference?

Comment: Two tables can be used as the source of the pivot table, and group, pu, and currency are grouped together to obtain the sum of the fields 8345, 6789, and 4589. The sql case can be found in almost the same process.

Comment: Yes I need the differences in amounts between the two tables matching the three criteria above.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to `join` the tables together and handle the "missing" values.  Assuming `-` really means `NULL`, you can do:

```
select t1.[group], t1.pu, t1.currency,
       nz(t1.[8345], 0) - nz(t2.[8345], 0) as diff_8345,
       nz(t1.[6789], 0) - nz(t2.[6789], 0) as diff_6789,
       nz(t1.[4589], 0) - nz(t2.[4589], 0) as diff_4589
from table1 as t1 inner join
     table2 as t2
     on t1.[group] = t2.[group] and
        t1.pu = t2.pu and
        t1.currency = t2.currency;
```

Comment: Adodb does not recognize the nz () function when I use adodb, is this true?

Comment: @Dy.Lee . . . It is an MS Access function.  Try using `COALESCE()` or `IFNULL()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I didn't make any typos in here, but the idea is you want to do a FULL OUTER JOIN so you don't lose any data from either table. then you just need to subtract one value from the other after specifying with the "ON" clause on how to join the two tables. Since some data may have info from Table 2 and Not from Table1, I did a check to see if it found anything, if not, I pull from the second table.

Side note. Be careful with columns that use reserved words (GROUP). I put brackets around them, so it should recognize it as a column name

```
SELECT
    IIF(ISNULL(T1.[group]), T2.[group], T1.[group]) AS [group],
    IIF(ISNULL(T1.[PU]), T2.[PU], T1.[PU]) AS [PU],
    IIF(ISNULL(T1.[currency]), T2.[currency], T1.[currency]) AS [currency],
    IIF(ISNULL(T2.[8345]), 0, T2.[8345]) - IIF(ISNULL(T1.[8345]), 0, T1.[8345]) AS [8345],
    IIF(ISNULL(T2.[6789]), 0, T2.[6789]) - IIF(ISNULL(T1.[6789]), 0, T1.[6789]) AS [6789],
    IIF(ISNULL(T2.[4589]), 0, T2.[4589]) - IIF(ISNULL(T1.[4589]), 0, T1.[4589]) AS [4589]
    FROM Table1 T1
    FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2
    ON T1.[group] = T2.[group]
    AND T1.[PU] = T2.[PU]
    AND T1.[currency] = T2.[currency]
```

Answer (score 0):

In sql, "group" is a reserved word, so change the field name "group" to "igroup".

Try,

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim strSQL As String
Dim Rs As Object
Sub test()
    Dim vR As Variant
    Dim str As String
    Dim i As Long
    str = "Select [igroup], iif(isnull([8345]),0,[8345] ), " & _
          "iif(isnull([6789]), 0,[6789] ),  " & _
          "iif(isnull([4589]), 0,[4589] )  " & _
          "from [Table2$] "

    getRs str
    vR = Rs.getrows
    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing

    For i = LBound(vR, 2) To UBound(vR, 2)
        str = "Update [Table1$] "
        str = str & "set [8345] =  iif(isnull([8345]),0,[8345] ) - " & vR(1, i) & ", "
        str = str & "[6789] = iif(isnull([6789]), 0,[6789] ) - " & vR(2, i) & ", "
        str = str & "[4589] = iif(isnull([4589]), 0,[4589] ) - " & vR(3, i) & " "
        str = str & " Where [igroup] ='" & vR(0, i) & "' "
        getRs str
    Next i

End Sub

Sub getRs(strQuery As String)
    Dim strConn As String
    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Rs.Open strQuery, strConn

End Sub
```